# I have a program that calculates the least common multiple of a set of numbers? But I seem to run into a logical error somewhere

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I get the correct value for least common multiple. However I don't know why I am getting all these numbers before displaying the LCM.
Below is a copy of my code [here is a pic of some ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg8RT.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<list>
 #include <iterator> 
 #include <algorithm>
 using namespace std;



int greatestCommonDivisor(int, int);
int leastCommonMultiple(list<int>&);

int main()
{

int num, size;


cout << "Enter how many number you want on your list: " << endl;
cin >> size;

list<int> intList;
ostream_iterator<int> screen(cout, " ");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter the number for the element " << i + 1<<": ";
    cin >> num;
    intList.push_back(num);
}

cout << "The numbers on you list are: ";

copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(),screen);
cout <<endl ;


cout << "The least common multiple is: " << leastCommonMultiple(intList) << endl; 

system("pause");
return 0;
}

int leastCommonMultiple(list<int>& intList)
{
int listLCM;
int i = 2;
while (true)
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (list<int>::const_iterator iterator = intList.begin(), end = intList.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator)
    {
        cout << *iterator;
        if (!(i%*iterator == 0))
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == true)
    {
        listLCM = i;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
return listLCM;
}
```

Comment: Search in the file for "cout" and remove the one that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't really comment yet so have to post a separate answer: your code is printing all iterations `cout << *iterator;` along with the final result. All you need to do is to get rid of that line to get desired output with no intermediate results

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I missed that. I was using that for testing and forgot to erase it.

Comment: There's a +1 button for it :)